# Is there a way to get TimeSpan to take two arguments?

Tags: c#

The `TimeSpan` struct takes three or more arguments by default(hours/minutes/seconds etc) but I'm wondering if there is any way to reduce this to two arguments(or even one) to have minutes/seconds or just seconds as arguments.

Comment: You probably looking for `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double seconds)` static constructor method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some options here:

The `TimeSpan.From...` methods

A factory method:

```
public static void MakeSpan(int mins, int secs) {
    return new TimeSpan(0, mins, secs);
}
```

A shortcut-lambda:

```
public static void main() {
    Func<int, int, TimeSpan> MakeSpan = (mins, secs) => new TimeSpan(0, mins, secs);
    var span1 = MakeSpan(1, 30);
    var span2 = MakeSpan(2, 05);
    // more to come
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to only pass seconds or minutes you can use the static-methods:

```
TimeSpan timeSpanDays = TimeSpan.FromDays(10);
TimeSpan timeSpanHours = TimeSpan.FromHours(10);
TimeSpan timeSpanMilliseconds = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
TimeSpan timeSpanMinutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
TimeSpan timeSpanSeconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
TimeSpan timeSpanTicks = TimeSpan.FromTicks(10);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a couple of static methods, that create `TimeSpan` from a single parameter:

```
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(double seconds)
TimeSpan.FromMinutes(double minutes)
```

You can read about all of the on [msdn TimeSpan page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.TimeSpan_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Notice the double parameter, so you can pass 1.5 minutes.